# Rails 5 API - Redundantly passing ID of Association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple structure of "A has_many B has_many C"

If I go into Rails console and do something like `A.first.Bs.first.C.create()` it'll create without an issue, however, if I use the API (or even Seeds actually) and so something like POST to `/api/v1/a/1/b` with the below create, I will always get rejected due to "Must belong to A" - Basically meaning it's trying to save as `a.id = null`. 
A = Campaign. B = Party for the below snippet.

```
def create
    @campaign = Campaign.find_by_id(params[:campaign_id])
    if @campaign.user_id == current_user.id 
        @party = Party.new(party_params)
        # @party.campaign_id = params[:campaign_id]
        if @party.save!
            render status: 201, json: {
                message: "Successfully saved the party!",
                party: @party,
                user: current_user
            }
        else
            render status: 404, json: {
                message: "Something went wrong: Check line 27 of Party Controller"
            }
        end
    end
end
```

The line I have commented out where I manually assigned `@party.campaign_id` resolved the error, but I am curious why it doesn't automatically pull from the information? Do `route resources` not function the same way as a `Campaign.first.parties.create` would?

Welcome any revision to this create method; It feels bulky, and likely not secure at all presently.

(Note `@campaign.user_id == current_user.id` is kind of a generic catch in case someone is trying to update someone else's campaign. I will likely re-visit this logic to make it more secure.)

Comment: Rails doesn't know what relationship these objects have, you have to build it yourself via `@campaign.parties.build(party_params)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails does not find anything automatically basing on routes, you need to do it by yourself.

In this case you can either assign id basing on params (as you did in the comment) or build `Party` as an element of `Campaign.parties` association

```
@campaign = Campaign.find_by_id(params[:campaign_id])
@party = @campaign.parties.new(party_params)
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense; In my last project I was following the `@campaign.parties` method - That's why this feels foreign.

Comment: When I bring `c` into the equation should I do something like 
`@a = A.find_by_id(params[:a_id]) 
@b = @a.bs.find_by_id(params[:b_id]) 
@c = @b.c.new(c_params)`
? I feel this might get excessive, but it seems more 'stable'

Comment: You can, vut it may be too much nesting